# Can't see or create files on Samba server (CentOS)

Tags: centos, samba, shared-folders

I'm trying to set up a file server using CentOS 7 and Samba.  I can connect to the server, and I can open the shared folders I've set up on the server.  However, I cannot see the contents, nor can I create new files or folders.  Trying to see the contents only results in Windows 10 showing that the folder is empty (which it isn't) and trying to create a new file or folder in one of the shared folders results in an access-denied message, even though I put in the credentials of the account that owns the folder.

I tried putting the account as a valid user in smb.conf, and that didn't work.  Switching guest ok to on in smb.conf didn't work either.

My config file is as follows:

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

[programming]
        path = /srv/samba/programming
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes

[video]
        path = /srv/samba/video
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the config file? Are linux permissions maybe contrasting the samba access rights (as they are higher in priority)?

Comment: Done.  Like I said, I'm logging in as the owner of the folders in question, so maybe the Samba permissions might not be working right?

Comment: Which are the directories in question? What is `ls -l` of said dirs? And also: AFAIK Windows 10 asks for a minimum of SMB v3 - so make sure that this is given (it shoudl be as otherwise there might be an error while mounting from Win10).